# Rails getting data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

app/models/road.rb

```
class Road < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :segments
end
```

app/models/segment.rb

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :road
end
```

app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb

```
@segments = Segment.joins(:road).select("segments.id, segments.name,
segments.road_id, roads.name AS roadname, ST_AsGeoJson(segments.geom) AS
segment_geom")
```

app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
<script>
  <% @segments.each do |segment| %>
    var segment<%= segment.id %> = new L.geoJson((<%= segment.segment_geom.to_s.html_safe %>), {style: statesegmentStyle})
    .bindPopup('id: <%= segment.id %><br>road_name: <%= roadname %>').addTo(segments);
  <% end %>
<script>
```

when reload the page I get this:

```
undefined local variable or method `roadname' for #<#<Class:0x00000003a14ef8>:0x007f7ea4628d90>
```

Comment: You need to call `segment.roadname` instead of just `roadname`

Comment: Thanks. That's it.